# How Can i Use Gdi print to print the express document in client?

Tags: asp.net, gdi

In our company，i got a request, print dhl & fedex express document on the website,
i write a class use gdi to print the express document, the function choose Printer to print the document on server.
Now We have a branch need the function too, but, how can i let them to choose the Printer on local?

gdi asp.net 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is fundamentally impossible.
The server has no access to the client computer.

Instead, you need to serve an HTML page (or PDF) and ask the user to print it.

Comment: i use page First,but the client computer use different Browser,and Resolution is different to, i have a idea~ Registered in the user client an Activex controls, and then use JavaScript to define the format of the report

Comment: Please, don't.  ActiveX controls should be considered a dead technology.

Comment: The browser and resolution should not make any difference.

Comment: and i want ask a question why u say that"ActiveX controls should be considered a dead technology" thank u very much ~best wishes~